# testcafe's Chrome refusing POST request to api (ipfs-http-client + infura)

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, ipfs

I'm trying test an app that uses `ipfs-http-client` module + `infura.io` as http provider. It doesn't work in testcafe's chrome (but it works everywhere else, like if I manually test my app in chrome). Here's the console error I'm getting:

`POST http://192.168.1.33:62108/gkheFCZHj/https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/add?stream-channels=true 400 (Bad Request)`

I'm not sure what testcafe uses, maybe a proxy or something? But it looks like `https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/add?stream-channels=true` is refusing the request. Any way to fix it? I'd like to keep using testcafe.

Comment: In general, if your request works fine without TestCafe and fails with it, this behavior looks like a bug.
I performed the POST request to 'https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/add?stream-channels=true' and got 400 http status code and the 'File argument 'path' is required' error message was thrown.
It seems that a wrong request url was calculated during test execution.

Comment: I see your application is rather complex.
It would help if you prepare a simple example when creating a bug report(https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe repository and attach your example to it.